# Getting unique count based on patterns mattching SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I wish to get unique count based on "classifyid" from the below mentioned string which is stored in SQL Server.

The table "tblSomething" has one column "SomeText" which has values like:

```
Row 1:
"<span classifyid="11111">Test 11111</span>
<span classifyid="12345">Test 22222</span>
<span classifyid="11111">Test 33333</span>"

Row 2:
"<span classifyid="11111">Test 11111</span>
<span classifyid="11111">Test 22222</span>
<span classifyid="11111">Test 33333</span>"

I am expecting the output as:
2 --    i.e. classifyid="11111" and classifyid="12345"
1 --    i.e. classifyid="11111"
```

Any solution using SQL script, please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need some sort of unique identifier for each row. If you don't have one in your table already, you'd need to use row number. Also, you'd either need your column to be XML already or you'd need to cast it as XML. Here's an example of how you could achieve this:

```
DECLARE @tblSomething TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), SomeText VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblSomething (SomeText) VALUES
('<span classifyid="11111">Test 11111</span><span classifyid="12345">Test 22222</span><span classifyid="11111">Test 33333</span>'),
('<span classifyid="11111">Test 11111</span><span classifyid="11111">Test 22222</span><span classifyid="11111">Test 33333</span>');

SELECT T.ID,
        Total = COUNT(DISTINCT A.B.value('@classifyid', 'varchar(max)'))
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, -- use "ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))" if you do not have a unique identifier. 
            X = CAST(SomeText AS XML)
    FROM @tblSomething
) AS T
CROSS APPLY T.X.nodes('span') AS A(B)
GROUP BY T.ID;
```

**EDIT:**

An example of how to do this with a recursive CTE instead:

```
DECLARE @tblSomething TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), SomeText VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblSomething (SomeText) VALUES
('<span classifyid="11111">Test 11111</span><span classifyid="12345">Test 22222</span><span classifyid="11111">Test 33333</span>'),
('<span classifyid="11111">Test 11111</span><span classifyid="11111">Test 22222</span><span classifyid="11111">Test 33333</span>');

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
           Val = SUBSTRING(SomeText, CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', SomeText) + 18, CHARINDEX('"', SomeText, CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', SomeText) + 18) - CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', SomeText) - 18),
           CIndex = CHARINDEX('"', SomeText, CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', SomeText) + 18)
    FROM @tblSomething
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S.ID,
           Val = SUBSTRING(S.SomeText, CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', S.SomeText, CTE.CIndex) + 18, CHARINDEX('"', SomeText, CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', S.SomeText, CTE.CIndex) + 18) - CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', S.SomeText, CTE.CIndex) - 18),
           CIndex = CHARINDEX('"', SomeText, CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', S.SomeText, CTE.CIndex))
    FROM @tblSomething AS S
    JOIN CTE ON CTE.ID = S.ID
    WHERE CHARINDEX('<span classifyid="', S.SomeText, CTE.CIndex) > 0
)
SELECT ID, Total = COUNT(DISTINCT Val)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. Once quick question, if content is having some additional data like "Hello <strong>world <span classifyid=..." then what additional changes would be required?

Comment: You might use `//span` instead of span if the span can be anywhere (e.g. `T.X.nodes('//span')`). The double forward-slash will look for any span anywhere in XML (as long as it's valid XML it shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: It's not a valid xml, it is more of a html contents w/o head and body tho! stuck!

Comment: Do you get an error when casting to XML? If not, you should be fine. If so, then there are other possible ways to do this (but less efficient than using XML and they may come with their own problems).

Comment: Yeah I get an error "XML parsing: line 3, character 36, well formed check: undeclared entity". Can you please suggest an alternate way?

Comment: I edited in an example of how to do this with a recursive CTE. If this doesn't work for you (say, for example, because a span element can have other attributes), then unfortunately I'm not going to be around for at least the next 12 hours to help.